# Lodash find with a range instead of exact match of numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm implementing a system in react-native where I use the onScroll handler to detect the Y offset from the top of the viewport. When the current scroll position equals a number stored in a separate object, it has to be detected.

This is my code now:

```
onActivitiesScroll = (event) => {
    let positionYTrack = _.find(
        this.state.trackHeaderCardPositionsY,
        { positionY: Math.floor(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y) }
    );

    console.log(positionYTrack);
}
```

The problem is this part: `{ positionY: Math.floor(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y) }`

The event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y is an exact number (floored) and positionY is a property in a state object. The problem is that when I scroll, it skips many scroll positions because of the limited number of frames the onScroll handler handles.

What this code is doing right now is:

if `Math.floor(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)` **exactly equals** one of the positionY property values in the state, it should log it. I want to do it like this:

if `Math.floor(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)` is within the range of current position - 10 and current position + 10, it should detect it.

Any idea how this can be achieved? I just can't seem to find a solution for this, even after sleeping over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_.find` also accepts a function to compare values. Here's a simple example you can use to find if `y` is in range:

```
onActivitiesScroll = (event) => {
    let positionYTrack = _.find(
        this.state.trackHeaderCardPositionsY,
        position => {
            const y = Math.floor(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
            const min = y - 10;
            const max = y + 10;
            return min >= position <= max;
        }
    );
}
```